# Updating stock on magento 2.1 using REST API - Error {"message": "Request does not match any route."}

Tags: vb.net, rest, api, magento, soapui

I am trying to get a stock item quantity updated on a magento 2.1 site using REST API.

I am coding in VB.net but I get the error JSON response {"message": "Request does not match any route."}

```
            Dim Access_Token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"

            Try

                Dim VATWebClient = New WebClient()
                VATWebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Accept) = "application/json"
                VATWebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/json"
                VATWebClient.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = "Authorization Bearer " & Access_Token
                Dim Response As String

                Response = VATWebClient.UploadString("http://www.xxxxxx.com/rest/V1/products/xxxx/stockItems/1", "{""stockItem"":{""qty"":100}}")


            Catch webEx As WebException
                Dim errorMessage As String = webEx.Message
                Dim errorStack As String = webEx.StackTrace

            End Try
```

I have also tried to setup SoapUI just to test to make sure that I am calling it right and I get the same error.

I read somewhere that the `webapi.xml` must be updated with the API which is required I am really hoping that's not the case as the host/web developer is not very accessible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UploadString will create a **POST** Request, as you can see form the API Docs, this API endpooint is **PUT** method only.

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_21.html#!/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1UpdateStockItemBySkuPut
```

I'm not too sure how to change the method in visual basic, but I'm sure it's not too difficult.

Comment: Thanks Andrew updated code to include "Put" as an over load e.g. `code` Response=WebClient.UploadString("http://www.derrys.com/rest/V1/products/M_T_P/stockItems/1", "Put", "{""stockItem"":{""qty"":100}}") `code` and I now get a 401 error which is related to Auth issue so solved my direct problem :) Thanks